# Adding hovering effects with a timeout in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

[See codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/timeout-hover-delay-xjwoz?file=/src/index.tsx)

I am trying to add a modal that shows up with a delay when hovering over a div. However, it's getting a bit tricky because, for example, if the timeout interval is 1000ms, and you hover over said div and then hover away from that div within the 1000ms, the modal will still show up. What I want to happen is for the modal to show up after the delay (e.g. 1000ms) *only* if you have maintained mouseover over the div for that delay period. How can I create this effect instead of the side effects I'm seeing now? Thanks!

**index.tsx:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const Modal: React.FC = () => {
  const divRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const divNode = divRef.current;

    const handleEvent = (event: Event): void => {
      if (divNode) {
        if (divNode.contains(event.target as Node)) {
          setTimeout(() => setShowModal(true), 1000);
        } else {
          setShowModal(false);
        }
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("mouseover", handleEvent);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleEvent);
    };
  }, [divRef]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="div" ref={divRef}>
        Hover Me
      </div>
      {showModal && <div className="modal">modal</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <>
    <Modal />
    <Modal />
    <Modal />
    <Modal />
  </>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a mouse out event that will hide the modal.

Call a funtion on 'mouseout' event listener and set the showModal to false. In that way, it will hide the modal if you move your mouse any time.

```
setShowModal(false)
```

Updated: Can you also set timeout to a variable and then on mouseout fire clearTimeout(variable_that_set_to_timeout)

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const divNode = divRef.current;
    let timeout = null;

    const handleEvent = (event: Event): void => {
      if (divNode) {
        if (divNode.contains(event.target as Node)) {
          timeout = setTimeout(() => setShowModal(true), 1000);
        } else {
          setShowModal(false);
        }
      }
    };

    const hideModal = (event: Event): void => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      setShowModal(false);
    };

    divNode.addEventListener("mouseover", handleEvent);

    divNode.addEventListener("mouseout", hideModal);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleEvent);
    };
  }, [divRef]);
```

[Link of sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-brattain-v9016?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks @Niloy but this won't prevent the timeout function from getting invoked after the delay period.

Answer (score 1):

You should really avoid changing the DOM when working with react. React isn't jQuery.
you could try making this your modal code:

```
const Modal: React.FC = () => {
  const [timeout, setModalTimeout] = React.useState(null);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="div" onMouseEnter={() => {
         timeout && !showModal && clearTimeout(timeout);
         setModalTimeout(setTimeout(() => setShowModal(true), 1000))
      }} onMouseLeave={() => {
        timeout && clearTimeout(timeout)
        setShowModal(false);
      }}>
        Hover Me
      </div>
      {showModal && <div className="modal">modal</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Sources:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html

Comment: If you want de modal not to close whenever the user hover out, bassically stop working as a [dropdown](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/), you can add `!showModal && setShowModal(false)` in place of `setShowModalFalse()`

Comment: Thanks Arthur however I need to use event listeners. This example is an abstraction of a specific implementation I am building in an app where I am also attaching a ref to `children` and performing these events based on multiple node events.

Comment: The code should work either way. just change your code from "mouseover" to mouseenter and add a mouseleave. But just so we are clear, you don't need to use the dom, even with multiple components. if you want to trigger something on various components, just add a context or something and add the code for changing said context on each separate component.

Comment: The important part of my code isn't where i'm placing the events, it's in the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to create a [`useTimeout`](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-timeout) hook and manage maintain the state of the hover.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import useTimeout from "./useTimeout";

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);

  //close after 3s
  useTimeout(() => setVisible(true), !visible && hovered ? 3000 : null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hover Timeout Example</h1>
      <div
        onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}
      >
        Hover me for 3s to show modal
        <div>Hover status: {hovered ? "true" : "false"}</div>
      </div>
      
      {visible && (
        <div>
          <h1>Modal</h1>
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hoverexample-nbb67)